# OpenCart template $module code

Tags: php, theme, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.1 but have a theme made for 1.4.9.

The following template code won't work with 1.5.1:

```
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
      <?php echo $module; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

> Undefined variable: modules.
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

What do I replace it with to work in 1.5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is modules defined? Do you know if you have modules set to show where that code is in the template?

You can do this:

```
<?php 
    if($modules){
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
          echo $module;
        }
    }
?>
```

This way if $modules is not set to anything, it ignores the foreach loop.

Comment: I receive "Notice: Undefined variable: modules in /.../common/home.tpl on line 20"

Comment: Notices are not as serious as errors and can usually be turned off in the php config. Do you have any modules specified for the location this code is placed?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I ended up rolling back from Opencart v1.5.1 to v1.4.9.6, which the template was compatible with.  2 hours later the author released a template compatible with 1.5.  :-S  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at my initial reply with the "isset" below for the "Notice" problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found a post about this question on opencart forums ..

[Migrate theme from 1.4.9 to 1.5.1 (Undefined variable)s](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=40667&p=195658)

Regarding the previous code, try the following :

```
<?php 
    if(isset($modules)){
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
          echo $module;
        }
    }
?>
```